# iOS Testflight invitation code

Tags: ios, testflight

I have my app written in Swift and have started testing using Testflight. Most of my users got the invitation email from Testflight and managed to install the beta version just fine.

However, a few people did not get the email and resending (add remove the user from testflight) does not solve the issue. So I am thinking to use te "redeem" function by sending them an Testflight invitation code.

How do I get such a code? (I checked in ITC but found nothing).
Is this the same code fir all testers by the way?

Comment: Did they check their spam box?

Comment: You don't have to send invitation code, they're already getting it in their mail.

Comment: Yes, I asked them to check their spam folder. Thanks for the suggestion. And I know that if they got the mail the dont need the code. My question is, if all of this fails, how can I get the redeem-testflight-invitation-code to still be able to help these users?

Comment: I'm having the same problem - sending the invite _does fail_, I'm sitting right here with a user who should have an invite to two of our apps, and they've only gotten one.  (And yes, we've checked the spam folder.)  Being able to create an invitation code would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm experiencing the same issue. It seems to be completely random, as to who it requests a code from, and who can just click through the email and set up the app.

Comment: I never figured it out